# What can I do with the WifiEnterpriseConfig api in android api 18?

Tags: api, wifi, enterprise

like the title said, What can I do with the WifiEnterpriseConfig api in android api 18?

Comment: This question is too open ended to be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise wifi settings are typically used in large (enterprise) wireless networks where certificates and/or username and passwords are used.

These networks are usually described as using 802.1x for authentication (EAP), and WPA2-AES (or WPA-TKIP, but this is being depreciated) for encryption.

Comment: Thank you, and what can I do with the new api in android api 18?

Comment: you can configure the enterprise settings. Where as you couldn't prior to api18.